# Runtime error '91' is prompting on my VB6.0 project

Tags: excel, vb6

Let me know where is the mistake on my code:

```
Dim oExcel As Object
Dim oBook As Object
Dim oSheet As Object



**Set oBook = oExcel.Application.Workbooks.Open(App.Path & "\Data" & "\" & Label4.Caption & "" & "\" & Label4.Caption & ".xls")**
'opens the filename workbook but this is where the ERROR pointing me at.

Set oSheet = oExcel.Application.ActiveSheet 'activate the first worksheet


oSheet.Range("A1").Value = Label1.Caption
oSheet.Range("B1").Value = Label2.Caption

oExcel.Save
oExcel.Quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code.

You never set your Application object. If Excel is not open, then you need to add:

```
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

In your lines that start with `Set ... = oExcel.Application` can be simplified to

```
Set ... = oExcel ' (no .Application)
```

because `oExcel` **is** your application-level object

```
Dim oExcel As Object
Dim oBook As Object
Dim oSheet As Object

Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(App.Path & "\Data" & "\" & _
    Label4.Caption & "" & "\" & Label4.Caption & ".xls")

Set oSheet = oExcel.ActiveSheet 'activate the first worksheet

oSheet.Range("A1").Value = Label1.Caption
oSheet.Range("B1").Value = Label2.Caption

oExcel.Save
oExcel.Quit
```

Then, it's unclear what `Label4` is. I don't see anywhere in your code where you assign an object to `Label4` prior to you using `Label4.Caption`. This also goes with `Label1` and `Label2`.

Comment: Hi, sorry im a beginner at programming, label 1 and label 2 are time and date that i want to store on my excel file. while label4.caption will determine which excel file to open which is stored in a folder defined as well by label4.caption.

Comment: you see, im creating an employee monitoring system, once they timed in, the time stamp will be saved on the excel file of the employee named after her firstname inside her own folder which is also under her first name

Comment: can you also give me an idea how i can identify if a time in data for a specific day is already saved on my excel file? and how i can proceed to the next row if i time in the next day? thank you very much!